# What is decade and octave in LTSpice simulation software

Tags: ltspice, simulation

What is type of sweep is decade or octave in LTSpice simulation software

Comment: I use 2000 points per decade or 600 points per octave, as equivalent samplings. I use at least that many points. Sometimes more.

Answer (score 13):

- Decade is a ratio of 10.
- Octave is a ratio of 2.

When talking about frequency response sweeps, those are frequency ratios.

- N points per decade means that for each order of magnitude (10x) increase in frequency, there are N phase+amplitude samples.
- M points per octave means that for each doubling in frequency, there are M phase+amplitude samples.

Thus, the density of the samples on the response plot is not linear in frequency, but logarithmic in frequency. Decade yields logarithm base 10, octave yield s logarithm base 2.

Comment: While I know what an octave is, it seemed odd to see it here next to decade made me wonder how odd the word is. If a decade is a ratio of 10, then surely an octa-ve should be a ratio of 8...

Comment: @ilkkachu 8 of one thing, half a dozen of another.

Answer (score 6):

Simulator will also ask you to specify number of points per decade/octave.
Say you specify 10 points.

For example, if you have selected 1 as your start value, 1000 as final value and choose sweep type as decade then, the simulator will simulate your circuit for 10 values between 1 & 10. 10 values between 10 & 100. 10 values between 100 & 1000.

For example, if you have selected 1 as your start value, 8 as final value and choose sweep type as octave then, the simulator will simulate your circuit for 10 values between 1 & 2. 10 values between 2 & 4. 10 values between 4 & 8.

So, basically, the sweep type tells the software how it should pick the values for the sweep.